# How to update the records in collection by few conditions in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{  
   "_id" : 1,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : [90], "mean" : 75, "std" : 5 },
      { "grade" : [], "mean" : 100, "std" : 4 },
      { "grade" : [], "mean" : 100, "std" : 5 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : [3,4,5,6], "mean" : 100, "std" : 5 },
      { "grade" : [], "mean" : 100, "std" : 3 },
      { "grade" : [g,a,s,e,f], "mean" : 100, "std" : 4 }
   ]
}
```

Consider the above example to be under the collection "Project", I need to write a Mongodb query to update the "std" only for the records for which the "grade" array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

With a `$[]` and a `$set` you can update a specific element of an array. (see the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_%5B%3Cidentifier%3E%5D))

To match not empty arrays I use `$not: { $eq: [] }`

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "grades.$[elem].std": "VALUE"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.grade": {
        $not: {
          $eq: []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8mBAQLE_uSr)

Comment: This would only update the first matching element in each document.